# Random Variable Problem w/ variance

Tags: random-variables, correlation

Three zero mean, unit variance random variables X, Y, and Z are added to form a new random variable, W = X + Y + Z. Random variables X and Y are uncorrelated, X and Z have a correlation coefficient of 1/2, and Y and Z have a correlation coefficient of -1/2.

a) Find the variance of W.

b) Find the correlation coefficient between W and X.

c) Find the correlation coefficient between W and the sum of Y and Z.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to ask a homework question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/) on meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be treated  very much as a "formula" question. Note that 
$$\text{Var}(W)=\text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y)+\text{Var}(Z)+2\text{Cov}(Y,Z)+2\text{Cov}(Z,X)+2\text{Cov}(X,Y).$$
For the covariances, recall that the correlation coefficient $\rho(U,V)$ is given by 
$$\rho(U,V)=\frac{\text{Cov}(U,V)}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(U)\text{Var}(V)}}.$$

Now you have all the ingredients to compute. Computation will not be hard.

Comment: You are welcome. Another standard formula, for $\text{Cov}(A,B+C)$ will come into play for the other problems.